# Parsing child elements with the same name on XSL

Tags: python, json, xml, xslt

I am wondering if there is a way to transfer over a parent element with all of its children elements that have the same element name using XSL.

For Example:

This is my XML code

```
<all>
    <data>
        <location>
            <coordinates>-80.326897</coordinates>
            <coordinates>25.586399</coordinates>
        </location>
    </data>
    <status>success</status>
</all>
```

I'm parsing it like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/all/data">
<xsl:value-of select="location/coordinates"/></b></center></td>
<xsl:value-of select="location/coordinates"/></b></center></td>
```

Obviously, I would like to get the values of both the Latitude and the Longitude, but of course, I am getting the same value (-80.32) for both.

How can I make it differentiate between latitude and longitude?

Comment: You can really only differentiate between first and second coordinate element, which are not actual coordinates, they are half of a coordinate each it seams. So the nicest solution would be to properly name the elements, because now you get two coordinate elements and assume the first is lat (or long) and the other is long (or lat).  Obviously if you cannot influence the xml structure than one of the below answers provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not `XSL` but since you tagged `python`, I suggest you use `BeautifulSoup`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

c = """
<all>
    <data>
        <location>
            <coordinates>-80.326897</coordinates>
            <coordinates>25.586399</coordinates>
        </location>
    </data>
    <status>success</status>
</all>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(c, 'lxml')
selection = soup.select('location coordinates')
selection = [float(e.text) for e in selection]

>>> selection
[-80.326897, 25.586399]
```

If you had more pairs, you can use odd and even to separate them. Or use a 2 stage process, first select `location`, which will return location tags, then for each of them return a `(x,y)` pair.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use index:

```
<xsl:value-of select="location/coordinates[1]"/>
<xsl:value-of select="location/coordinates[2]"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged this as `python`, I presume you're using `libxslt` i.e. XSLT 1.0. In XSLT 1.0, the instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="location/coordinates"/>
```

gets the value from the **first** `coordinates` in the first `location`.

---

To get the value from the second `coordinates`, you *could* use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="location/coordinates[2]"/>
```

or simply change your:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/all/data">
```

to:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/all/data/location/coordinates">
```

(this is assuming that there will be only one occurrence of both `data` and `location` in the XML document).

Answer (score 0):

Just add another level of looping, for example:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/all/data">
  <div>
    <xsl:for-each select="location/coordinates">
       <b><xsl:value-of select="."/></b>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </div>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Note though that if it gets any more complex than this, then you should be thinking about using template rules.